# Lotus Notes Designer - Show dialog list based on value from another field

Tags: lotus-notes

When creating a new program in Lotus Domino Designer, I thought of trying to create a dialog list (Process) which shows different list based on value of another field (Assy).

Example:

```
-------------
| Assy      |
-------------
| Frame     |
| Armature  |
-------------

If Assy = Frame

----------------
| Process      |
----------------
| Frame Insert |
| Adhesive     |
| Vacuum       |
| Magnetize    |
----------------

If Assy = Armature
----------------------
| Process            |
----------------------
| Commutator Insert  |
| Winding            |
----------------------
```

For the Assy field I tried using this formula:

```
@If(Assy="Frame";"Frame Insert":"Adhesive":
"Vacuum":"Magnetize & Appearance";Assy="Armature";
"Commutator Insert":"Winding";"")
```

During testing I noticed 2 things:

1. When I choose Frame in Assy field, the Process field will give me the correct dialog list. But when I switch Assy field to Armature and check back on Process field, the choices still remains as Frame selection. The same applies for when I choose Armature first.
2. When I commit to a selection in the Process field, both data in Assy and Process field disappears. Then when I try to reenter the information the Process field won't show any of my selections even after picking new Assy.

What seems to be the problem here? Do I need to make any changes in options or is my code faulty?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You need to set the setting "Refresh Choices on Document refresh" in the "Process" Field (same Tab as the Formula) and the setting "Refresh fields on keyword change" in the Assy- field.

I usually do this with another field "ProcessList", computed (or computed for display), that is above the Process- field and under the "Assy" field and contains the formula you posted above.

Then in the process field the formula is simply "ProcessList".

In normal use the "ProcessList" field is hidden. 
This has the advantage that you can "debug" better by removing the hide when of the ProcessList- field and check the values directly.